# Tic-Tac-Toe BIG board using functions and 2D arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, function, console-application, cout

I've tried solving this problem for over a week. 
My assignment is to cout (display) a big tic-tac-toe board that looks like this:

```
0000 | 1111 | 2222
0000 | 1111 | 2222
0000 | 1111 | 2222
0000 | 1111 | 2222
------------------
3333 | 4444 | 5555
3333 | 4444 | 5555
3333 | 4444 | 5555
3333 | 4444 | 5555
------------------
6666 | 7777 | 8888
6666 | 7777 | 8888
6666 | 7777 | 8888
6666 | 7777 | 8888
```

Some suggested functions in the instructions are: 
*"populateBigArray()//fills the 12X12  array with vales 0-8 assignValueToBigArray()// used to populate the 4X4 section of the 12X12 array which corresponds to a specific move by either the human or the computer"*

I feel like I understand 2D arrays and I am able to print one 4x4 block of numbers. However, everything I try results in the blocks printing straight down, not in a 3x3 structure or all of the numbers printing in one long line.

The closest I've gotten is the function below, however, it's not exactly using a 2D array which is the point of the assignment, and I know trying to manipulate a spot once one is chosen by a player isn't really possible with this.

```
//Global constants
const int BOARD_ROWS = 3;
const int BOARD_COLS = 3;
int main()
{
    displayBoard();
    return 0;
}
    void displayBoard()
    {
        int spot = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < BOARD_ROWS; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < BOARD_COLS; col++)
            {
                cout << spot << spot << spot << spot
                    << " | " << (spot + 1) << (spot + 1) << (spot + 1) << (spot + 1)
                    << " | " << (spot + 2) << (spot + 2) << (spot + 2) << (spot + 2)
                    << endl;
            }
            cout << "------------------" << endl;
            spot = spot + 3;
        }
    }//end displayBoard
```

I'm definitely a newbie and appreciate any help. Thanks!!!

Comment: When you used the debugger and executed the statements one at a time, which statement is causing the issue?

Comment: [Works here](http://ideone.com/0o7dCe). What's your issue actually? That you forgot providing a declaration for `void displayBoard();` before main?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you didn't write the functions suggested nor used a 2D array, "which is the point of the assignment" as you said...

Maybe you can start from the 2D array and see how the functions may look like:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

const int BOARD_SIZE = 3;
const int SECTION_SIZE = 4;
constexpr int BIG_ARRAY_DIM = BOARD_SIZE * SECTION_SIZE;

void populateBigArray( int b[][BIG_ARRAY_DIM] );
void assignValueToBigArray( int b[][BIG_ARRAY_DIM], int r, int c, int val );
void printBigArray( int b[][BIG_ARRAY_DIM] );

int main() {
    int board[BIG_ARRAY_DIM][BIG_ARRAY_DIM];

    populateBigArray(board);

    printBigArray(board);
    return 0;
}
```

Then you can implement those functions, starting with something like this:

```
void populateBigArray( int b[][BIG_ARRAY_DIM] ) {
    int k = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; ++i ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; ++j ) {
            assignValueToBigArray(b,i,j,k);
            ++k;
        }
    }
}

void assignValueToBigArray( int b[][BIG_ARRAY_DIM], int r, int c, int val ) {
    int row = r * SECTION_SIZE;
    int col = c * SECTION_SIZE;
    for ( int i = 0; i < SECTION_SIZE; ++i ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < SECTION_SIZE; ++j ) {
            b[row + i][col + j] = val;
        }
    }
}

void printBigArray( int b[][BIG_ARRAY_DIM] ) {
    for ( int i = 0, l = 1; i < BIG_ARRAY_DIM; ++i, ++l ) {
        for ( int j = 0, k = 1; j < BIG_ARRAY_DIM; ++j, ++k ) {
            cout << b[i][j];
            if ( k == SECTION_SIZE ) {
                if ( j == (BIG_ARRAY_DIM - 1) ) {
                    cout << '\n';
                } else {
                    cout << " | ";
                    k = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        if ( l == SECTION_SIZE  &&  i != (BIG_ARRAY_DIM - 1) ) {
            cout << "------------------\n";
            l = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I wrote multiple versions which used a 2D array, however, the output was not anything close to this. The blocks would just line up one under another or I would just have a single line, not a 3x3 block of 4x4 numbers. The code I posted was the only version that displayed the board properly, though I would not have been able to manipulate it. I appreciate your help. I was in awe of the assignValueToBigArray function.

Comment: @VanidadVelour You are welcome, glad you liked it. If you think this answer your question you can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it or upvote if you find it useful.